# Adding a field to mongodb with existing data in TS

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb

Assuming I have a TypeScript application that runs off mongodb that already has some amount of user data, and I want to add a feature that would involve adding a new field to the user objects.

What would be the best way to integrate this into my code? Is it to run a query to add the field to all existing objects, or to set the field as optional in my types and adding it if it doesn't exist when accessing a document?